# ASP.Net Web API Action Result

Tags: asp.net

I'm building an ASP.Net Web API application and i have the following code...

```
public IHttpActionResult GetCustomers() {            
    var customers = context.Customers.ToList();
    return Ok(customers);
}
```

I'm using the Ok() method to return customers because i'm using an IHttpActionResult return type.

Now if i have the following method

```
public void DeleteCustomer(int id) {
  var customerInDb = context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

  if (customerInDb == null) {
      NotFound();
  }

  context.Customers.Remove(customerInDb);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Can I use NotFound() method here when the return type of my ActionMethod is void???

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what your NotFound method does? provide more code if you expect help

Comment: NotFound() is a build-in method of ASP.Net Web API

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to validate this in the controller and call delete only if the Id is valid? This way you could add a simple Modelerror and be done with it.

Comment: Why did you make the return type of your DeleteCustomer method void then? Return IHttpActionResult...

Comment: According to REST-ful conventions when you make a HttpGET request you generally have an ActionResult with a return type of IHttpActionResult that returns Ok() to return a statusCode 200..When you make a HttpPOST request to create a record you generally have an ActionResult with a return type of IHttpActionResult that returns  Created() to return a statusCode 201...when you make a HttpDelete request to delete a record the return type of the ActionResult is void..So i need to know if i return NotFound()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Void does not have a return type. So you can try to call `NotFound()`, but I'm not sure if this would even compile - Haven't tried. Why don't you just go with an out of the box `IHttpActionResult`?

```
public IHttpActionResult DeleteCustomer(int id)
{
    var customerInDb = context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
    if (customerInDb == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    context.Customers.Remove(customerInDb);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(customerInDb);
}
```

Using `IHttpActionResult` is the more elegant version. If the id is invalid, you can just safely exit your method and tell the calling client that something went wrong. If everything went well, you're just giving the client a thumbs-up. IF you return your deleted entity or just an empty `Ok()` should not matter at this point.

Using void may or may not delete the entity in your data storage. The client would never know, because the server would not return any response.

Comment: If i just go with IHttpActionResult for Delete and return Ok() it will work..but i want to know what is the generally accepted convention...from what i've read Delete methods SHOULD(not HAVE TO) return void

Comment: I've never heard of such a convention. Why is not responding better than telling the client what the outcome is?